# Преобразовать строку байты

Tags: python-3.x

У меня есть конфиг файл, в котором одно значение записано в виде строки байт:

```
name = b'\xd0\x91\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd1\x82\xd1\x8b'
```

При получении значения,  *name* содержит строку:

```
"b'\xd0\x91\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd1\x82\xd1\x8b'"
```

То есть не тип bytes, а а тип str. Подскажите, как из строки такого вида вернуть тип bytes?

Comment: `При получении значения` вот с этого момента подробнее: 1) как значение получено? 2) показали бы в вопросе код получения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наверное, это имелось в виду:

```
import ast
s = r"b'\xd0\x91\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd1\x82\xd1\x8b'"
b = ast.literal_eval(s)
```

Comment: Ну, это как бы у меня в коде и есть, думал, есть другой способ более, скажем, стандартный.

Comment: @Xyanight ну так в конфиге (если это ini-файл) читаются только строчки, потому как формат ini универсальный, не только под Питон. Может, удобнее конфиг просто на Питоне написать, или на JSON?

Comment: @Xyanight если вы хотите байты получить, то вам следует `b''` интерпретировать как Питон-код (как django settings). Если вы получаете `"b''"`это значит что вы НЕ как Питон-код читаете файл. Попробуйте: `import project.settings` (предполагая `name= b''` записано в `project/settings.py` файле). Если на входе у вас не Питон модуль и вы хотите только одну строчку как Питон-константу интерпретировать, `ast.literal_eval()` как раз это и делает.

Comment: Это Kivy project. Видимо, literal_eval придется оставить.

Comment: @Xyanight: вы можете импортировать свои модули и в Kivy проекте.

Comment: Да. Могу. Но какое отношение это имеет к вопросу?

Comment: @Xyanight ещё раз мой первый комментарий причитайте (видно ли в нём слово import?)¶ В сторону, как вы думаете зачем я `@Xyanight` добавляю в начале комментария?